# richfaces panelMenu when double choose same menuItem looses page format

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have very strange behavior using richfaces panelMenu, if I choose twice the same menù item, with no other actions in the middle, the page looses all format.
I'm curently using rf 4.3.2 and I've tested with firefox 23 and ie 10.
This is the first menù select
[image]

and this is the second
[image]

Any hint would be appreciated

menu.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:form id="menuForm">
  <rich:panelMenu style="width:200px; background: white"  itemMode="server" groupMode="ajax"
            groupExpandedLeftIcon="triangleUp" groupCollapsedLeftIcon="triangleDown"
                    topGroupExpandedRightIcon="chevronUp" itemLeftIcon="disc"
                    topGroupCollapsedRightIcon="chevronDown">
        <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{menu.menuGroup1}" >
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem11}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="11"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem12}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="12"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem13}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="13"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
   <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem14}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="14"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{menu.menuGroup15}" >
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem151}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="151"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
   <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem152}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="152"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem153}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="153"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{menu.menuGroup2}">
     <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem21}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="21"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
     <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem22}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="22"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
     <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem23}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="23"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
     <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem24}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                <f:param name="curVal" value="24"/>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{menu.menuGroup25}" >
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem251}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="251"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem252}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="252"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        <rich:panelMenuGroup  label="#{menu.menuGroup3}">
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{menu.menuGroup31}" >
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem311}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="311"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem312}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="312"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem313}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="313"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{menu.menuGroup32}" >
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem321}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="321"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem322}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="322"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem323}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="323"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem324}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="324"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{menu.menuGroup33}" >
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem331}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="331"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem332}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="332"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem333}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
                    <f:param name="curVal" value="333"/>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        </rich:panelMenuGroup>
     <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem98}" action="#{menuBean.getCurAction}" >
            <f:param name="curVal" value="98"/>
        </rich:panelMenuItem>
    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{menu.menuItem99}" action="#{menuBean.optionLogout}" >
            <f:param name="curVal" value="99"/>
        </rich:panelMenuItem>
    </rich:panelMenu>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

menu bean

```
package bean;

import bean.util.JsfUtil;
import entities.ESMenuAction;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import org.richfaces.component.UIPanelMenuGroup;
import uty.ESMessageManager;
import uty.ESUty;

@ManagedBean(name = "menuBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ESMenuBean implements Serializable {

final String sMenuConst4Action = "menuAction", sMenuConst4Item = "menuItem";
HashMap<String, String> hmKeys = null;
TreeMap<String, ESMenuAction> tm = null;
Locale curLoc;

public ESMenuBean() {
    ResourceBundle rb;
    try {
        rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.menu");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        ESUty.getSystemLogger().setMsg4Error("ESMenuBean Error Accessing properties.menu Resource Bundle - " + t);
        return;
    }
    loadMenuItems(rb);
    curLoc = ESUty.getCurLocale();
    rb = null;
}

public String getCurAction() {
    String s = tm.get(getCurOption()).getMenuAction();
    if (s.equals("ESTipReco_list") && !ESUty.getESUserRights().isAdmin()) {
        JsfUtil.addMessage(ESMessageManager.getMessageNoLog("errMenuOptNotAllowed", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, curLoc));
        ESUty.getSystemLogger().setMsg4Info("ESMenuBean.getCurAction Menu' Option " + s + " not Allowed for " + ESUty.getESUserCur().getU1usr());
        return null;
    }
    if (ESUty.getESUserRights().isAut4Menu(s)) {
        ESUty.getSystemLogger().setMsg4Info("ESMenuBean.getCurAction Menu' Option " + s + " Selected for " + ESUty.getESUserCur().getU1usr());
        return s;
    }
    JsfUtil.addMessage(ESMessageManager.getMessageNoLog("errMenuOptNotAllowed", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, curLoc));
    ESUty.getSystemLogger().setMsg4Info("ESMenuBean.getCurAction Menu' Option " + s + " not Allowed for " + ESUty.getESUserCur().getU1usr());
    return null;
}

private String getCurOption() {
    return JsfUtil.getRequestParameter("curVal");
}

public ESMenuAction getMenuObject(String inMenuAction) {
    try {
        return tm.get(hmKeys.get(inMenuAction));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return null;
    }
}

public SelectItem[] getMenuItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(new ArrayList(tm.values()), true);
}

private void loadMenuItems(ResourceBundle inRb) {
    try {
        tm = new TreeMap();
        hmKeys = new HashMap();
        Enumeration<String> en = inRb.getKeys();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String sKey = en.nextElement();
            if (!sKey.startsWith(sMenuConst4Item)) {
                continue;
            }
            String sMenuOption = sKey.substring(sMenuConst4Item.length());
            tm.put(sMenuOption,
                    new ESMenuAction(inRb.getString(sMenuConst4Action + sMenuOption),
                    inRb.getString(sKey),
                    sMenuOption));
            hmKeys.put(inRb.getString(sMenuConst4Action + sMenuOption), sMenuOption);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        ESUty.getSystemLogger().setMsg4Info("ESMenuBean.loadMenuItems Error Loading Menu' Items " + t);
    } finally {
    }
}

public String optionLogout() {
    ESUty.getSystemLogger().setMsg4Info("ESMenuBean.optionLogout Session Closed for " + ESUty.getESUserCur().getU1usr());
    uty.ESUtil.logout();
    return tm.get("99").getMenuAction();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code, please ?

Comment: Hi, is the code shared enough ?